# Spring boot backend server in Docker Container of AWS EC2

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, docker, amazon-ec2

I am trying to run an application with Spring boot(Java-17) as my back end and React as my front end. Both front end and back files are running smoothly when I run them locally with 'docker-compose up'. When I run the same docker file by adjusting small configurations(SSL certificates) which are not the problem, the whole EC2 instance is freezing and not responding(even the front end doesn't work one the EC2 instances freezes). As soon as I tried to request the backend the whole EC2 instance froze and the only way to start it again was to stop the instance completely and start it again.

I used maven to clean package my project using 'mvn clean package' which creates a jar file. I am using that jar file to run the docker file for my server-side using that jar file. I think I am not supposed to directly package my Java application to the jar and use it but I am not sure.

This my projects github code link:
https://github.com/Nithin-Kamineni/Book-Wise

This is my backend docker file:

```
# Use the official OpenJDK base image with Java 17
FROM openjdk:17-oracle

# Set the working directory in the container
WORKDIR /usr/src/server

# Copy the packaged JAR file into the container
COPY target/spring-boot-library-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar  app.jar

# Expose the port that your Spring Boot application listens on (if necessary)
EXPOSE 8080

# Set the entry point command to run your Spring Boot application
CMD ["java", "-jar", "app.jar"]
```

docker-compose.yml:

```
version: "3.8"

services:
  mysql:
    container_name: db12w
    image: mysql:8.0.33
    restart: always
    environment:
        MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
        MYSQL_DATABASE: reactlibrarydatabase
        # MYSQL_PORT: 3306
    networks:
      - shared-network
    volumes:
      - mysqlvolume:/var/lib/mysql
      - ./db:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d

  # mysql-workbench:
  #   container_name: mysqlwbcontainer
  #   image: linuxserver/mysql-workbench:8.0.33
  #   restart: always
  #   environment:
  #     CUSTOM_USER: abc
  #     PASSWORD: root
  #     CUSTOM_PORT: 5050
  #   ports:
  #     - 5050:5050
  #   networks:
  #     - shared-network
  #   depends_on:
  #     - mysql
    # volumes:
    #   - mysql-workbench-volume:/var/lib/mysql
  
  nginx:
    image: nginx
    # container_name: nginx_container
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - ./default.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
      - ./certs/localsslexample-key.pem:/etc/nginx/certs/devopsbyexample-key.pem
      - ./certs/localsslexample.pem:/etc/nginx/certs/devopsbyexample.pem
    ports:
      - 80:80
      - 443:443
    networks:
      - shared-network
    depends_on:
      - server
      - client

  server:
    container_name: bookwise_server
    restart: unless-stopped
    image: bookwise-server-image:1.0.0
    build:
      context: Backend
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    environment:
      # - spring_datasource_driver-class-name=
      - spring_datasource_url=jdbc:mysql://db12w:3306/reactlibrarydatabase
      - spring_datasource_username=root
      - spring_datasource_password=root
    ports:  #outside:inside(container) #8443
      - 8080:8080
    networks:
      - shared-network
    depends_on:
      - mysql

  client:
    container_name: bookwise_client
    restart: unless-stopped
    image: bookwise-client-image:1.0.0
    build:
      context: Frontend
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    # ports:  #outside:inside(container)
    #   - 3000:3000
    # environment:
    #   - REACT_APP_API=https://localhost/api/api/fdfd
    networks:
      - shared-network
    depends_on:
      - server
volumes:
  mysqlvolume:
  # mysql-workbench-volume:
networks:
  shared-network:
    driver: bridge
```

If you need any additional information on the code I used you can look at my GitHub repository. As for output or error, my EC2 instance is simply freezing at that spot itself as soon as I make a backend request. Until then even the logs of the server service are fine.

Comment: Hi. What instance type?

Comment: T2 micro, I have chosen all free tier options for launching the instance.

Comment: I think `t2.micro` is too slow to run Java and build a typical SPA, that is why you are freezing. I'd recommend stopping instance, changing instance `t2.large` and testing for an hour. You won't be charged for 1 hour. LMK.